# Spark xgboost4j 8300 labels got XGBoostModel training failed error bug no clearly errors

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, classification, xgboost

After StringIndexer OneHotEncoder and vectorAssembler my train data is like this:

```
+--------------------+----------+
|            features|classIndex|
+--------------------+----------+
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,8]...|     945.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,10...|     468.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,8]...|    2125.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,8]...|    1231.0|
|(12,[1,2,3,4,8],[...|    1754.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,8]...|    3790.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,8]...|    1714.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,8]...|    1046.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,8]...|    8145.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,8]...|    6643.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,8]...|    1729.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,6]...|    4211.0|
|(12,[1,2,3,4,6],[...|     444.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,6]...|     444.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,6]...|    3948.0|
|(12,[0,1,2,3,4,6]...|    6784.0|
.....
```

My xgboost para is:

```
val xgbParam = Map("eta" -> 0.1f,
    "max_depth" -> 2,
    "objective" -> "multi:softprob",
    "num_class" -> 8249,
    "num_round" -> 100,
    "num_workers" -> 2)

val xgbClassifier = new XGBoostClassifier(xgbParam).
    setFeaturesCol("features").
    setLabelCol("classIndex")
```

When I use xgbClassifier.fit(xgbInput), I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostError: XGBoostModel training failed
```

I really don't know where something went wrong.
Full logs are below, anyone knows why?

```
Exception in thread "main" ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostError: XGBoostModel training failed
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.ml$dmlc$xgboost4j$scala$spark$XGBoost$$postTrackerReturnProcessing(XGBoost.scala:511)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$1.apply(XGBoost.scala:404)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$1.apply(XGBoost.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$.trainDistributed(XGBoost.scala:380)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassifier.train(XGBoostClassifier.scala:196)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassifier.train(XGBoostClassifier.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:118)
    at com.tencent.mig.profile.basicprofile.UserProfile.Test_Code$.main(Test_Code.scala:143)
    at com.tencent.mig.profile.basicprofile.UserProfile.Test_Code.main(Test_Code.scala)
19/06/08 18:26:40 ERROR RabitTracker: Uncaught exception thrown by worker:
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitReady(ThreadUtils.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:610)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2094)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:934)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:932)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:932)
    at ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost$$anonfun$trainDistributed$1$$anon$1.run(XGBoost.scala:397)
19/06/08 18:26:45 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Comment: Is this really a *classification* problem? With how many classes?

Comment: @desertnaut   8249